# Redirect a subdomain AND pages to a domain?

Tags: redirect, mod-rewrite

Years ago, someone setup a subdomain or alias on our site and some pages, but we've had some problems clearing them out and need all old, broken references redirected to our home page.

While our site is "example.com" the subdomain is "www2.example.com" even though we can't find "www2" listed on the host cpanel subdomains, not in the .htaccess, alias etc. I did find a CNAME record and redirected it to to our home page (example.com).

However, there are lingering pages, such as www2.example.com/page1 that get redirected to example.com/page1 and a 404 error instead of going to the home page at example.com.

So I added this to the .htaccess file, but it does not seem to be working:

```
# www2 redirect
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www2.example\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://example.com [R=301,L]
</IfModule>
```

Thoughts?

Comment: Is the older version of the site hosted on the same server?

Comment: No, there never was a site on the server for www2, but it was sent to a 3rd party landing page service via a CNAME record. That account is long gone. So no real idea what pages were created, although I did do a site:www2... search to find some that are still indexed.

Answer (score 0):

Based on the standard cPanel setup, each sub-domain will have its own folder at main public directory("/public_html/www2").  So, you need to redirect every file from that sub domain/folder to main domain/folder.

Your final .htaccess file would be this simple config:

```
//301 Redirect Entire Directory
RedirectMatch 301 /www2(.*) //$1
```

Hope it helps!

Comment: The thing is, it doesn't appear to have been setup as a subdomain, there is not subdomain listed in the cpanel, but there was a CNAME record pointing www2 to a 3rd party landing page SAAS. This was years ago, and that account is long gone, so we are chasing down the page references created in the 3rd party software via 404 errors.